# R shinyMobile error when I upgraded to 0.7.0

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I am getting the following error in R when I upgraded to the newest (unreleased) version of the R shinyMobile package. The error:

```
Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'framework7-5.1.1'; `directoryPath` = ''
  [No stack trace available]
```

This is really annoying because even after downgrading the package... I still get the same error. Has anyone seen this error before and know how to fix it?